# Trying to import a CA root certificate into the JVM trust store

Tags: java, keytool

Starting off by letting you all know that I am a newbie on this!

I have two files that were given to me to add to the trust store to allow our Java application to talk to a fax service. One is api.fax.crt and the other is api.fax.ca.
I have been adding the certs to the servers in the following manner:

```
cd /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
aws s3 cp s3://BlahBlah/temp/api.fax.ca .
aws s3 cp s3://BlahBlah/temp/api.faxa.crt .
sudo update-ca-trust
sudo service tomcat restart
```

This does seem to work but it sometimes takes ten minutes to work and some times it takes hours. By working I mean that it lets the code using it communicate with the end fax service
I read up a bit and found that I should probably be installing these in the JVM trust store.
I tried the following:

```
cd /usr/java/latest/lib/security/
aws s3 cp s3://BlahBlah/temp/api.fax.ca .
aws s3 cp s3://BlahBlah/temp/api.fax.crt .
sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias faxage -file api.fax.com.ca -keystore /usr/java/latest/lib/security/cacerts -storepass blahblah
sudo keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias faxage2 -file api.fax.com.crt -keystore /usr/java/latest/lib/security/cacerts -storepass blahblah
sudo service tomcat restart
```

Doing it this way I have never been able to connect to the fax service.

Is there a better way? Should I be adding this to the Java location or the ca-trust location? Should I be adding both the ca and crt files? Why might I be having the delay before it works in the first example?
Thanks all for any insight!!!!

FYI - The errors I get are below. I looked up these errors and the answers I found are to add the certs to the "/usr/java/latest/lib/security/cacert" keystore - which I try and it does not work.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:259)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:642)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:461)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:361)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:450)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:427)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:178)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:716)<br>
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:970)<br>
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)<br>
at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)<br>
at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)<br>
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity.writeRequest(ByteArrayRequestEntity.java:90)<br>
      And many more........
```

Comment: I'd prefer using a separate keystore for CA certificates not trusted by default by system or jvm. Reason is that the default list of CAs may be overwritten by an update (system or jvm version)

Comment: ErnieAndBert, I can see you're using tomcat but I'm guessing you're making an outgoing connection to the fax service? In other words you're making an HttpsUrlConnection and that's failing? If so, what Varontron is recommending won't help at all.

Comment: gusto2 - how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `server.xml` as well to inform it of the path to your `keystore`:

From the [tomcat 7 documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File)

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

The rest of the document may be useful as well